# Connection to a Wi-Fi network without password

Tags: raspbian, wifi, raspbian-jessie, wireless, bash

I'm currently working on my Raspberry Pi, running Raspbian, trying to connect to a network without password using iwconfig.

ifconfig wlan0 results :
 ifconfig wlan0

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:33:09:43
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::74f6:3f1d:f617:df31/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1089 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:154874 (151.2 KiB)
```

and my iwconfig wlan0

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=31 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

My script is quite simple (and the wifi's ESSID is "aaa"):

```
#!/bin/bash
ifconfig wlan0
iwconfig wlan0 essid aaa 
dhclient wlan0
```

When I try to connect just by using sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid aaa i got an error:

```
Error for wireless request "Set ESSID" (8B1A) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.
```

I can see with the GUI that the symbol of the wifi start to blink, like the Raspberry was trying to connect to the network, but it stay like the previous state (unconnected/connected to another essid)
At the end of the script I get a message "RTNETLINK answers: File exists". I already did

```
sudo ip addr flush dev wlan0
```

to erase it, the message disapears but I'm still not connected

Do you have any idea to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first stop `wpa_supplicant` and `hostapd` from running via:

```
sudo killall wpa_supplicant
sudo killall hostapd
```

Then bring down the `wlan0` Interface:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
```

Switch the `wlan0` interface from master to managed mode:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode managed
```

Bring the `wlan0` interface up again:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

And now you should be able to connect to the open Access Point via

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid aaa
```

Comment: When I try to stop wpa_supplicant i get a "no process found" error. Then I try iwconfig wlan0 essid aaa and I got a "Error for wireless request "Set ESSID" (8B1A) :" error. I don't relly know why, I keep looking

Comment: Did you use `sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid aaa` or without `sudo`? Because without `sudo` you get the exactly same error you mention.

Comment: I use with sudo,, or I log as root user

Comment: What does it say in the second line of the error message, after `Error for wireless request "Set ESSID" (8B1A) :` ?

Comment: Could you maybe also post the Output of `ifconfig wlan0` and `iwconfig wlan0` inside your question right before you try to connect to the Access Point `aaa`?

Comment: I've edited my post ! the second line is "    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported." and i'm quite sure that my raspberry support wifi without encryption

Comment: your interface was in master mode. I assume you used `wlan0` as interface for an access point?!
I updated the answer. Please give it a try now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you found the problem. I will read again ifconfig/iwconfig man for sure. Thanks again, I hope you will have a good week !

Comment: You are very welcome. A good week to you, too!